# Can i send another ajax request while waiting for one ajax method?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Can i send another ajax request while waiting for one ajax method?
Basically, My first ajax function is a long running function, so I want to send another ajax method to enquire about the status of the first AJAX method which I am showing in a progress bar.

Comment: You can. you don't need to wait for response of ajax since they are asynchronous. You can send any number of request.

Comment: if the second one is related to the first one somehow, then you can put the second request in success function of first. OR mark both asyn:false.. IF not.. then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. But, My problem here is, when I send the second AJAX request, the first AJAX gets suspended.How can I make both AJAX requests function simultaneously in the web application.